# what is the semantic term for this type of sentence?

Tags: verbs, terminology, semantics

I know this sentence means a change of state because of the verb *broke*.

> John **broke** the window.

What is the semantic term for this sentence given no change of state occurred?

> John **viewed** the parade.

Comment: A change of state occurred: the parade got viewed.

Comment: really, are all transitive verbs are change of state?

Comment: Transformative vs. passive or observational?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Can you give more examples of sentences in the two categories (hopefully with other verbs)?

Answer (score 3):

This question is asking about [aktionsart or lexical aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_aspect). Aktionsart divides verbs into five categories, based on whether they take time or not, whether a change of state occurs, and whether they [are telic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telicity) (have an end point or goal). Wikipedia has [a nice simple table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_aspect#Categories) showing how these factors combine together.

[image: A screenshot of Wikipedia's table]

The window breaking is telic (has a change of state and an end point), and is probably non durative, because breaking glass is very quick. This would make it an **achievement**. If it was conceptualised more as an event which took time then it would be an **accomplishment**.

Viewing the parade has duration but is atelic, which makes it an **activity**.